# Losing information due to limit in query

Tags: sql, presto

I have a table tablename with columns col1-col10. Not every row has col4 populated, but every row has col1, col2, col3 populated. I want to get all {col1, col2, col3} tuples for when col4 satisfies a condition, then get all rows that match the tuple {col1, col2, col3} from tablename.

I have this query:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where exists (
    select 1
    from mytable t1
    where 
        t1.col1 = t.col1 
        and t1.col2 = t.col2 
        and t1.col3 = t.col3 
        and t1.col4 >= 1000
)
LIMIT 1000
```

The size of the table is very large so I have to add the **limit**. Due to the limit, for some {col1, col2, col3} not getting all rows in the result dataset. I want to then get all rows that match the tuple {col1, col2, col3} from tablename.

I don't mind have less {col1, col2, col3} tuples in my result, but I want complete information for the ones I do have.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Very large? It's all relative, isn't it?

Comment: In this context, I mean I cannot do without adding a limit of some sort. Moreover, since I only care about getting complete information about some (about 100) unique {col1, col2, col3}

Comment: Sqlite and mysql are two different database products with different implenentations of sql. Remived the fonflicting product tags. Pls add the one back that you actually use!

Comment: Why did you add a `LIMIT` clause?

Comment: @TheImpaler just want all rows for about 100 {col1, col2, col3} tuples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't mention which database but the following query should run faster. You can do:

```
select t.*
from t
join (
  select distinct col1, col2, col3 
  from t
  where col4 >= 1000
  limit 100
) x on t.col1 = x.col1 and t.col2 = x.col2 and t.col3 = x.col3;
```

With the following indexes, the query should become faster:

```
create index ix1 on t (col4, col1, col2, col3);

create index ix2 on t (col1, col2, col3);
```

Comment: What kind of join is this? Inner, outer? I ran this with a limit of 10 , and it didn't return any rows. I wonder why

Comment: I see it's an inner join, which should work. Not sure what I am missing

Comment: If you can provide a few rows of sample data it would be easier to verify your case. This query should work in accordance with the description of the question. And yes, it's an inner join.

Comment: I had a bug in my query unrelated to this issue. thanks a lot The Impaler

Answer (score 0):

A much more efficient approach is to use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when col4 > 1000 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by col1, col2, col3) as cnt_matches
      from mytable t
     ) t
where cnt_matches > 0;
```